# CakePHP: Could not load configuration file

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to get a cakephp project up and running from a svn checkout on my mountain lion computer.

I changed all the cache write permissions find but now I have one last fatal error that's not letting the app run.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ConfigureException' with message 'Could not load configuration file: /Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/app/Config/core-production.php' in /Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/lib/Cake/Configure/PhpReader.php:77
```

> Stack trace: #0
>   /Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(267):
>   PhpReader->read('core-production') #1
>   /Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/app/Config/core.php(287):
>   Configure::load('core-production') #2
>   /Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(76):
>   include('/Users/mike/cak...') #3
>   /Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(146):
>   Configure::bootstrap(true) #4
>   /Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/app/webroot/index.php(81):
>   include('/Users/mike/cak...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   /Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/lib/Cake/Configure/PhpReader.php on
>   line 77

it fails on this line inside index.php inside webroot

```
 if (!include ('Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
    $failed = true;
}
```

Any ideas as to what could be the cause?

Comment: Do you have a file called core-production.php in /Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/app/Config?

Comment: Did you try echo 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php'; and checked the included file?

Comment: @jimiyash that file does not exist, this project is coming from an ubuntu install, I forgot to mention that in the post. However that install didn't have that file either and we were confused why machine was trying to get that file.

Comment: @bitfox it echos "Cake/bootstrap.php" when doing the ini_set('include_path', ROOT.DS.'lib'.PATH_SEPERATOR.init_get('include_path')); I evaluated the path and it echoed out "/Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/lib:/Users/mike/cake2cribs/cake2cribs/lib:.:" which seemed odd and may be a cause for error. It seems like you are getting something as you are setting it with the init_get and init_set in the same line.

Comment: @Mike: I found another question similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382293/cakephp-trying-to-install-an-application-in-a-subdomain. The problem seems may be related to your Apache virtualhost configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done an Ubuntu install, I've always just downloaded the source and put it in my webroot. Anyway, cake always expects to have a file called core.php which holds all the config info. Maybe the Ubuntu install just expects core-production.php, so you might just need to copy the core.php file in app/Config and rename it to core-production.php.

Comment: at the end of the core.php file there is a check to see if CAKE_ENV is defined and if it isn't production is defaulted. I'm curious to why that didn't cause an issue for their environments. If I comment out the line that tries to load the core-production.php it seems I get a little further into the application. Just missing some plugins now.

Comment: Well, since you did checkout a svn repository, it's possible that whoever was working on it before just added the core-production.php to their ignore file. Maybe it had some information they didn't want to share, who knows.